# how to check the checkboxes if the value in xml is yes and if no than unchecked

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

My XML Looks like this whose name is Data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<CATALOG>
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <CD />
  <CD>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <LocationID>wqe</LocationID>
    <ChangeValueFor>qwe</ChangeValueFor>
    <Banner>wew</Banner>
    <DataEntry>Yes</DataEntry>
    <LocalView>No</LocalView>
    <Export>Yes</Export>
    <View>qwe</View>
    <ActiveView>wqe</ActiveView>
    <HelpFile>qwe`qw</HelpFile>
    <Location01>qwe</Location01>
    <Location02>eq</Location02>
    <Location03>we</Location03>
    <Location04>wqew</Location04>
    <Location05>qws</Location05>
    <Location06>sds</Location06>
    <Location07>wde</Location07>
    <Location08>sd</Location08>
    <Location09>sad</Location09>
    <Server>31 March 2014 testing with font</Server>
    <Server2>171.21.102.11</Server2>
    <Server3>171.21.102.11</Server3>
    <CodeBase>CodeBase2</CodeBase>
    <CodeBase2>ZaidiTest</CodeBase2>
    <CodeBase3>test222</CodeBase3>
    <ClassiscID>ClassID312131313</ClassiscID>
    <ClassiscID2>31 amrch testing for font</ClassiscID2>
    <ClassiscID3>ClassID2</ClassiscID3>
    <Theme>VashnoDevi</Theme>
    <Theme2>class</Theme2>
    <Theme3>class</Theme3>
    <Theme4>Theme2</Theme4>
    <Theme5>Ser</Theme5>
    <Theme6>Themes1test</Theme6>
  </CD>
```

I want when `<DataEntry>` `<LocalView>` and `<Export>` is Yes than my check box is Y checked and when remain No than unchecked(As it is).

My xslt file is as follows:
I just want to add only one checkbox only on data entry please tell me where I am doing mistake

Myxslt file is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body style="font-family:Helvetica Neue">
        <!--<Div id="ListingScreen" style="display:Yes;">-->
        <Div id="ListingScreen">
          <table border="1" width="1024px" >
            <tr bgcolor="blue">
              <FONT
            style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0000ff">
                <FONT color="white">
                  <STRONG>
                    Maintenance of Parameters for Cube Access
                  </STRONG>
                </FONT>
              </FONT>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" colspan="8">
                <img src="http://localhost:51242/Images/AFKLLogo.png" alt="Smiley face" width="210"></img>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8">
                <h1>WPTesting - Cube List Web Part</h1>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="8" align="center">
                <input type="Button" id="btnAddMasterData" value="Add Master Data" onclick="javascript:AddMasterData()"/>
                <input type="Button" id="btnAdd" value="   Add    "   onclick="javascript:location.href='AddMaster.aspx'"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th id="location">Location ID</th>
              <th>Data Entry</th>
              <th>Export</th>
              <th>Local View</th>
              <th>Banner</th>
              <th>Server</th>
              <th>View</th>
              <th>Locl</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="CATALOG/orderByTitle">
                <xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD" order-by="+ TITLE">
                  <tr>
                    <td onclick="javascript:FillEditScreen(this.innerText);">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <p style="display:none;">
                          <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                        </p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="LocationID"/>                                      
                      </a>
                      <input type="checkbox"   id="chkdataentry" />
                      <xsl:value-of select='DataEntry'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="chkLocalView" />
                      <xsl:value-of select='LocalView'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox"  id="chkExport"/>
                      <xsl:value-of select='Export'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Banner"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Server"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="View"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Location01"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="CATALOG/orderByTitleDesc">
                <xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD" order-by="- TITLE">
                  <tr>
                    <td onclick="javascript:FillEditScreen(this.innerText);">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <p style="display:none;">
                          <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                       </p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="LocationID"/>

                      </a>
                    </td>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="DataEntry" value="Milk">
                      <xsl:if test="CATALOG/CD='Yes'">
                        <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
                      </xsl:if>
                    </input>
                    <!--<td>
                      <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="chk" value="Milk"/>
                    </td>-->
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox"  checked="true" name="Export"  value="export"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox"   checked="true" name="LocalView" value="export"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Banner"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Server"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="View"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Location01"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="CATALOG/orderByArtist">
                <xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD" order-by="+ ARTIST">
                  <tr bgcolor="blue">
                    <td>
                      <input type="Button" id="btnArtist" value="Impala"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="Milk"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox"  name="Export" value="export"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" checked="true" name="LocalView" value="export"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Banner"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Server"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="View"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Locl"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </table>
        </Div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main code is Like thins but it is giving me error dont know why

```
<input type="checkbox" name="DataEntry" value="Milk">
                  <xsl:if test="CATALOG/CD='Yes'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:if>
                </input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually said what your error is, or shown what output you expect, but I can see a number of issues.

Firstly, your XLST namespace is wrong `http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl` was an old one used by Microsoft before the formal XSLT specification got released. It should be `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`. If you change it, you will need to make some changes to your XSLT. Instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD" order-by="+ TITLE">
```

You will need to do this, as `order-by` is not allowed in the formal definition.

```
<xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD" >
   <xsl:sort select="TITLE" order="descending" />
```

Secondly, if your current `xsl:if` check you check `CATALOG/CD='Yes'`, but you are already positioned on the `CD` so the expression needs to be relative to that. And it looks like you really need to check `DataEntry` element anyway, so you should use this in the condition.

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="DataEntry" value="Milk">
    <xsl:if test="DataEntry='Yes'">
      <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
  </input>
</td>
```

Also note that in your XSLT sample you had not enclosed the `input` tag in a `td`, which would have affected how it was rendered on the page.

Finally, although it wouldn't cause an error, you have a lot of repeated code in your XSLT. Consider using a template for the `CD` element instead.

Try this XSLT as an example

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body style="font-family:Helvetica Neue">
        <Div id="ListingScreen">
          <table border="1" width="1024px" >
            <tr>
              <th id="location">Location ID</th>
              <th>Data Entry</th>
              <th>Export</th>
              <th>Local View</th>
              <th>Banner</th>
              <th>Server</th>
              <th>View</th>
              <th>Locl</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="CATALOG/orderByTitle">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="CATALOG/CD">
                  <xsl:sort select="TITLE" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="CATALOG/orderByTitleDesc">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="CATALOG/CD">
                  <xsl:sort select="TITLE" order="descending" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="CATALOG/orderByArtist">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="CATALOG/CD">
                  <xsl:sort select="ARTIST" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </table>
        </Div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CD">
    <tr>
        <td onclick="javascript:FillEditScreen(this.innerText);">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <p style="display:none;"><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></p>
            <xsl:value-of select="LocationID"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="DataEntry" value="dataentry">
              <xsl:if test="DataEntry='Yes'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
            </input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Export" value="export">
              <xsl:if test="Export='Yes'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
            </input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="LocalView" value="localview">
              <xsl:if test="LocalView='Yes'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
            </input>
        </td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Banner"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Server"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="View"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Location01"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```